# Spring Boot does not return any data from query for composite primary key

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I have a list classes ProductId and Product. I also have a ProductRepository for the Product class. The ProductId is a composite primary key.
How can I write a criteria query for a list of composite ids for the following structure:

```java
@Data
class ProductId{
    Long productId;
    Long categoryCode;
}
          
@Data
@Document(collection = "products")
class Product {
                
    @Id
    ProductId id; 
               
    Long productName: string;
    Long category;
    Long quantityInStock;
                
    @PersistenceCreator
    Product(ProductId id,Long productName,Long category,Long quantityInStock){
        this.id = id;
        this.productName= productName;
        this.category = category;
        this.quantityInStock = quantityInStock;

    }
}
```

Here is the repository definition

```java
public interface ProductRepository extends MongoRepository<Product, ProductId> {
   
}
```

When I create a query using

```java
Product id = productRepository.findById(id); // Returns Optional.empty
```

This also does not return any data., returns empty list

```java
public List<Product> find(List<ProductId> ids) {                 
    Query query = new Query();
    Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("id").in(ids);
    query.addCriteria(criteria);
    List<Product> results = mongoTemplate.find(query, Product.class);
    return results;
}
```

Here is the view from Studio 3T

```js
{
    "_id": {
         "productId": 872223334,
         "categoryCode": 4
    },
    "productName": "Decantor Jacket",
    "category": 'Plaid-Item',
    "quantityInStock": 4001
}
```

How can I fix these queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For composite keys, you need to build your query this way:

```
db.product.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          $and: [
            {
              "_id.productId": 872223334
            },
            {
              "_id.categoryCode": 4
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          $and: [
            {
              "_id.productId": 872223335
            },
            {
              "_id.categoryCode": 5
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/n2-UavJz1ip)